# Query on response value

Tags: python, django, mongodb, elasticsearch, kibana

How to write a conditional query on multiple fields?
Explain: I have an index let say "**case**" and the fields are "**title**", "**secondTitle(contain nested obj)", "source(contain nested obj)**". Now I want to search on title and want number of document inside of **secondTitle,** which also contains in **source** field of another document.

```
PUT /case_indx_tmp_tmp
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title":{
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "title":{
            "type":"keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "secondTitle":{
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "second_title":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields": {
              "secondtitle":{
                "type":"keyword"
              }
        }
          }
        }
      },
      "source":{
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "source_title":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields": {
              "sourcetitle":{
                "type":"keyword"
              }
        }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /case_indx_tmp_tmp/_doc/1
{
    "title" : "Case 1",
    "secondTitle" : [
        {
            "case_title" : "Case 2"
        }
    ],
    "source":[
      {
        "source_title":"Case 3"
      },
      {
        "source_title":"Case 4"
      }
    ]
}
PUT /case_indx_tmp_tmp/_doc/2
{
    "title" : "Case 2",
    "secondTitle" : [
        {
            "case_title" : "Case 3"
        },
        {
            "case_title" : "Case 4"
        },
        {
            "case_title" : "Case 1"
        }
    ],
    "source":[
      {
        "source_title":"Case 1"
      }
    ]
}
PUT /case_indx_tmp_tmp/_doc/3
{
    "title" : "Case 3",
    "secondTitle" : [
        {
            "case_title" : "Case 5"
        },
        {
            "case_title" : "Case 4"
        },
        {
            "case_title" : "Case 1"
        }
    ],
    "source":[
      {
        "source_title":"Case 2"
      },
      {
        "source_title":"Case 5"
      }
    ]
}
PUT /case_indx_tmp_tmp/_doc/4
{
    "title" : "Case 5",
    "source":[
      {
        "source_title":"Case 3"
      },
      {
        "source_title":"Case 4"
      },
      {
        "source_title":"Case 2"
      }
    ]
}
```

> ### if search term is "Case" then it will return
> title: Case 1
> secondTitle_count: 1
>
> ### title: Case 2
> secondTitle_count: 3
>
> ### title: Case 3
> secondTitle_count: 2
>
> title: Case 5
> secondTitle_count: 0

my solution was, to iterate all documents which return after search query and make new bool query object for the "source" field where values are from secondTitle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and [nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) with [value count aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html).

In the below query,

1. The `match` query is used to get only those documents that contain `case` in the `title` field.
2. Terms aggregation will create a bucket of all the unique field values of the `title` field.
3. Nested aggregation along with Value count aggregation will aggregate over the terms aggregation result, and get the count of documents present under `secondTitle` object.

```
POST case_indx_tmp_tmp/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "case"
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "top_tags_per_comment": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "title.title"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "Services": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "secondTitle"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "secondTitle_count": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "secondTitle.case_title.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"aggregations" : {
    "top_tags_per_comment" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Case 1",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "Services" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "secondTitle_count" : {
              "value" : 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Case 2",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "Services" : {
            "doc_count" : 3,
            "secondTitle_count" : {
              "value" : 3
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Case 3",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "Services" : {
            "doc_count" : 3,
            "secondTitle_count" : {
              "value" : 3
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Case 5",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "Services" : {
            "doc_count" : 0,
            "secondTitle_count" : {
              "value" : 0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Tanvir Ahmmed did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you ;-)

Comment: @Tanvir Ahmmed if the answer helped you resolve your issue, then please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer! TIA ;-)